# NSPredicate in many to many relation ship

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have the following entities relationship A <<-->> B, ok?
Now, during the application's life I have two objects of type A, and I'd like to know ALL the objects of B that contains those objects...

I tried with ...ANY aRelationWithA.att == objectA1.att... over the B entity, but, what about the other object...? I found a SUBQUERIES solution but is the same result because with a ...SUBQUERY(aRelationWithA, $object, $object.att == objectA1.att)..., but again, what about the other object...?

I need the B object that contains those A objects in these relation ship A <<-->> B, regards!

Comment: Doesn't `SUBQUERY(aRelationWithA, $object, $object.att==objectA1.att && $object.att==objectA2.att)` work?

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Temporaly I used two NSPredicates to validate that condition...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"B"];
propertyRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY aRelationWithA.att == %@", objectA1.att];
NSError *error;
NSArray *collection1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSArray *collection2 = [collection1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY aRelationWithA.att == %@", objectA2.att]];
if (collection2.count) NSLog(@"There are some objects with that condition");
```

I appreciate your response or some reference to learn more about this topic!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
NSFetchRequest *r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"B"];
[r setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY relationshipToA = %@ OR ANY relationshipToA = %@", objectA1, objectA2]];
```

Comment: @specktro you need to include more information in your question.  Please describe *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish, because you've gotten several answers that should have worked but apparently aren't.  Show us what you're doing, and what you want it to be doing.

Comment: Hi Dave, there is not another way to explain my question, I have this relationship A <<-->> B... in some part of the application's life I get two objects of type A and I want to know the object B that contains them with a NSPredicate over a NSFetchRequest in some NSManagedObjectContext. I've probed the solutions offer here but none of the answers solved my problem, my solution gets the right result but for me it isn't efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try use this predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY aRelationWithA in %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objB1, objB2, nil];
```

Comment: i udated my answer. i removed ".attr" from predicate

Comment: Your solution doesn't fail but doesn't deliver the right results, thanks!